# Signing Under Duress in school?

Tags: united-kingdom, criminal-law, minor, education

I am a minor in a UK public school. I was told I had to write a statement about a rule I broke in school and sign it. I missed out a piece of information, and they told me I had to write about that part, too.  Is this legal?

They made me write about something which I'm arguing isn't actually true, and they can and (I'm guessing will) use it against me.

Comment: What kind of school?  Are you a minor?  How did they compel you to write and sign?  Does the alleged infraction involve an actual crime, or is it just a violation of the school's rules?

Comment: Public State school, I am a minor, they told me I had to write about it, it's violation of school rules, but what they THOUGHT I did, would be a crime,

Comment: So you mean to say, "I was told by a public school authority that I had to write and sign a statement confessing to a criminal action that I maintain I did not commit?"

Comment: I don't know about the UK but in Belgium signing under pressure is afaik not allowed. If that can be "proven", the statements signed can be invalidated.

Comment: Yes, feetwet, that's exactly what happened

Comment: Are you being charged with a crime, or is the school using this as evidence that you violated one of their rules? There are two parts: is it actually a *crime*, and are the police and courts involved?

Comment: Adding the words "Under duress" next to your signature may be a good idea.  If they are trying to get you to write a confession, and you can, find a citizens advice bureau and visit them.  (I'm not in the UK, but if they have a lawyer you can talk to, even better).  Try and do this before turning in any work.

Answer (score 1):

Yes. This is legal.

A school acts *in loco parentis* which means in lieu of a parent, in the discipline of its students for what it perceives to be infractions and has broad authority to do so. This is considerably more true in Britain, where there is not so great a tradition of absolute individuals rights, than it is in the United States, where this is that tradition.

If you are unwilling to admit that what they consider is a violation of a rule is really wrong or a violation of a rule, then you are not just someone who has screwed up, but someone who defies their rules and that is grounds for expulsion because a school is allowed to teach only people who recognize its legitimacy.

Answer (score -1):

You can put "V.C." next to your name, which is short for the Latin "Vi Coactus" meaning "having been forced".

Comment: This is about signing a statement, not entering a contract; that entire paragraph is irrelevant here. The third paragraph is commentary on (your perception of) an education system, and ostensibly false to boot.